# How to do robust logging in Deno Deploy?

Tags: javascript, deno, deno-deploy

I've been evaluating Deno Deploy as a solution for a middleware listener used in a larger application, and one thing that I'm still struggling with is that the Deno Deploy playground doesn't seem to have any obvious persistent logging feature. It shows very rudimentary logs for the current deployment only in the logs tab. I want to be able to pay for several days worth of application logs to be persisted to some place where I can analyze and search them later. No doubt there are third-party services for this, but I'd rather not slow down my listener by using them. Seems like they would be fastest if implemented in a more native way in Deno Deploy. This seems like it should be a very important, basic feature. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not missing anything: Deploy offers no persistent storage that is local to your module code or its runtime instance — all persistent data must be sent and received via network requests.

There's a GitHub issue related to this topic that you can subscribe to for updates: [denoland/deploy_feedback#39 - Observability with Deno Deploy](https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/39)

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions for a popular logging service that already has compatible client libraries for Deno? I keep getting a "npm specifiers have not yet been implemented for this sub command" when trying to import npm packages.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830699/how-to-do-robust-logging-in-deno-deploy/74831134?noredirect=1#comment132071843_74831134) @cayblood Logging has a pretty large surface area, so without much more specific requirements, suggestions are hard to make. I [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74831134/2) the answer with a link to a tracking issue on GitHub: that's probably a good place to start reading/researching.